# Return all documents from a function using MongoDB and show them using express

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, module

How can I display all documents from MongoDB using a function that connects to the client and gets values. Tried using `toArray` method but id does not appear when I send it as a response to postman.

**database.js**

```
exports.getFromDb = (uri) => {
 MongoClient.connect(uri, (err, db) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("ToDoList");
     var documents = dbo.collection("ToDo").find({});})}
```

**index.js**

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    return res.json(getFromDb(uri))
});
```

Comment: I recommend looking at this repository as a good starting point for what you want to do. https://github.com/bezkoder/node-express-mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch something from the database, you should wait the return.

Something like this.

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await getFromDb(uri);
        return res.status(200).json(data);
    } catch (err) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: It shows value when I use `console.log` in **database.js** but if I send this value through response or `console.log` it in **index.js**, it gives undefined.